# snapshot_restore_exception migrating ElasticSearch 7 indices between servers

Tags: elasticsearch

We want to migrate an ElasticSearch v7 index from server 1 to server 2.

How can we copy and restore a snapshot from one server to another?

The offical documentation seems to assume both servers share the same physical storage. These servers do not "know" each other and have completely seperate disks. In our case we:

1. Create the same repository `foo` on both servers
2. Run a snapshot `foo1` on server 1
3. Create the `/snapshots/foo` directory on server 2
4. Verify the repo on server 2
5. Run a snapshot `footest` on server 2 to verify files are written to `/snapshots/foo`
6. Copy across the `/snapshots/foo` directory from server 1 to server 2
7. Run the restore of `foo1`:

```
POST /_snapshot/foo/foo1/_restore
{
  "indices": "foo"
}
```

The error is:

```
{
  "error": {
    "reason": "[foo:foo1] snapshot does not exist",
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "reason": "[foo:foo1] snapshot does not exist",
        "type": "snapshot_restore_exception"
      }
    ],
    "type": "snapshot_restore_exception"
  },
  "status": 500
}
```

When we check the repo:

```
GET /_snapshot/foo/*
```

We can see only one snapshot (which we created on server 2). We cannot see the snapshot we copied across from server 1.

So how does one transfer a snapshot to server 2?

Comment: I would skip step 5 or make sure to empty the `/snapshots/foo` folder on server 2 before step 6. Can you try?

Comment: I have already tried that unfortunately. Indeed I have emptied the entire server 2 directory/repo "foo" and copied it across from server 1.

Comment: You should then simply use an S3 bucket for your repository, so you can share them between servers.

Answer (score 1):

@Marc there are few options for you to copy data from one server to another in terms of indices:

1. Configure CCR (cross cluster replication) for your index and let it sync between the two servers (which can be on separate machines. network/ etc... they should just be able to communicate)
2. You can have a single repository created which can be accessed by both servers (using shared IAM user or role assuming it's on AWS). You can then take snapshot of your index from server1 and restore the snapshot in server2.
3. Not recommended but you can copy ${path.data} files from server1 to ${path.data} in server2.

However, the main question here would be: are your server1 and server2 running on same ES version ?

Comment: 1. ) Worth noting that CCR is commercial feature in Elastic (free with OpenSearch though) 2) doesn't work because of "These servers do not "know" each other and have completely seperate disks" 3) Not recommended indeed :-)

Comment: 2) doesn't work because of "These servers do not "know" each other and have completely seperate disks".... That's the reason why snapshot is being used to ship the data I believe.

Comment: In that case, OP should use an S3 bucket as I suggested instead of a filesystem repository.

Comment: We ended up doing a remote `/_reindex` between the servers which took several hours. I guess we could NFS map a directory common to both servers and try 2). Will report back on that. In the past we have had success with 3) but this time we only wanted to move certain indices.

Comment: `we could NFS map a directory` -> this is something similar to what I mentioned in point # 2 to snapshot required indices at certain location accessible to both servers and restore them on sever 2 :-)